# Always turning left necessarily takes you back to your starting position?

Tags: graph-theory, network

In a very general street network of two-way roads, if at every intersection you always turn in the same direction, say, leftmost, is it guaranteed that you return to your starting point?

The street network generically corresponds to a finite spatial 2D undirected non-planar graph (due to bridges and tunnels) with nodes at the intersections. I'd guess that this is trivially true for planar graphs (and probably linked to the [Right-hand rule](https://www.nytimes.com/1989/09/06/opinion/l-why-right-hand-rule-for-mazes-works-075389.html) or the [Wall follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm#Wall_follower) method for maze solving). I've failed so far to find any counter-example, i.e., any graph where I wouldn't go back to the starting position. As going more than once through the same edge or node is allowed, dead ends aren't a problem.

Comment: How are dead-ends handled? Is "turning left" there a U-turn?

Comment: @Mike Yes, you take the leftmost edge: if there's only one, then it's the leftmost (and the rightmost) one (and since you must have arrived there via the same edge, it's indeed a U-turn).

Comment: What if the only choices are right turn or make a u-turn? [Are we assuming that vertices of degree 2 i.e., bends in the road no intersections are edges?]

Comment: One way the leftmost edge can be defined is: the edge with the largest (counterclockwise) angle with respect to the U-turn edge (i.e., the one through which you arrived) - which means *leftmost* stands for *as left as possible*, which might mean going straight ahead or even right. It's not possible to have only "right turn or u-turn", because a right turn still has an angle larger than zero (U-turn), so I'll call it "leftmost".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Your position is described by a pair $(v,w)$ of intersections, meaning you are on a road connecting $v$ to $w$ and heading towards $w$. Every position $(v,w)$ is preceded by a **unique** position $(u,v)$, given by heading along the road from $w$ to $v$ and making the nearest *right* turn.  Let's call your sequence of positions $$(x_0,x_1),(x_1,x_2),\dots,(x_n,x_{n+1}),\dots$$
Since there are finitely many positions, this infinite list must have a repeat. Let $i<j$ be the indices of the earliest such repeat, $(x_i,x_{i+1})=(x_j,x_{j+1})$. I claim this means $i=0$, so that $(x_j,x_{j+1})$ is a return to your starting point. If not, then the repeated positions would be preceded by the **same** position $(x_{i-1},x_i)=(x_{j-i},x_j)$, contradicting the fact that $i,j$ was the earliest such repeat.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very fine explanation. Do you know of any book or other source that has this statement? (I might need it for a citation.)

Comment: A very similar puzzle with the same solution method appears in G. A. Galperin and A. K. Tolpygo (1986). _Moscow Mathematical Olympiads,_ Prosveshchenie. I heard of this puzzle in Peter Winkler's _Mathematical Mind Benders_, p 66, which cites the olympiad source.

Comment: Thanks again. I couldn't find an open version of Winkler's book, but the Olympiad source can be found on-line, e.g., [here](https://diendantoanhoc.net/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=22389) (problem 35.2.7.4, page 104, solution in the page 193).

Comment: It took me some time to convince myself of your last statement, so I took the liberty of adding the sketch of a demonstration to your answer - please don't hesitate to correct it or revert the edit if you see fit.

Comment: Do you agree that this [that the 1st repeat happens at the starting edge] can be seen by *reductio ad absurdum*? An attempt: suppose that the first repeat of a sequence of edges $\{\overline{ab},\overline{bc},\overline{cd},...\}$  **isn't** the initial street $\overline{ab}$, but, say, $\overline{cd}$: then, since $\overline{cd}$ is the (unique) leftmost edge of $\overline{bc}$, this latter edge is a previous repeat, which means $\overline{cd}$ (and any edge other than the starting one) actually can't be the first repeat.

Comment: @stafusa Yes, that is s very good explanation. I would approve such an edit, and may add it in myself later

Comment: Thanks. I hope you do so: I've tried, but someone was quick to reject the edit.